# Difference between first and following column by conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have a data frame that is formatted like this but with a lot more variables:

```
structure(list(var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), var2 = c(1, 1, 2, 4, 
3), var3 = c(4, 1, 3, 2, 5), var4 = c(2, 5, 4, 1, 3), var5 = c(5, 
4, 3, 1, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

In R, I would like to evaluate the changes between the first and the remaining variables.
When the first one is between 1 and 3 and the following one is between 4 and 5, I want the following variable to take the value +1. If the first variable is between 3 and 5 and the subsequent variable is between 1 and 2, the subsequent variable should be -1. In case neither condition is met, it should be 0.
I would like to do this by referring to the column positions, not the names.

I came up with this but its very slow:

```
test3 <- lapply(1:nrow(test), function(i) {
  if (test[i, 2] %in% 3:5) {
    mutate(test[i, ], across(!1,
                           ~ case_when(. %in% 1:2 ~ -1,
                                       . %in% 3:5 ~ 0,
                                       TRUE ~ NA)
    ))
  } else if (test[i, 2] %in% 1:3) {
    mutate(test[i, ], across(!1,
                           ~ case_when(. %in% 1:3 ~ 0,
                                       . %in% 4:5 ~ 1,
                                       TRUE ~ NA)
    ))
  } else {
    mutate(test[i, ], across(!1, ~ NA))
  }
})

test3 <- do.call(rbind, test3)
```

How might I do this in a faster manner?
The expected output is this:

```
structure(list(var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), var2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
0), var3 = c(1, 0, 0, -1, 0), var4 = c(0, 1, 1, -1, 0), var5 = c(1, 
1, 0, -1, -1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: hi!
I'm trying to understand the logic -- when you say subsequent, you mean colwise? or rowwise? also is the first column always the anchor? lastly you use subsequent twice, so it a column requires two columns to the left as a reference point for its value? if so how does the second column  base its values?

Comment: @alejandro_hagan The first one is always the anchor. And then it should be "compared" to all following columns. When using subsequent twice I just mean that whichever variable following the first is in question should take the new variable. Does this help?

Comment: hi -- yes  I think I understand the logic to replicate columns 1-3, however I'm confused why there is a -1 in row 3 of the second column? it is compare 3 with 2 which are both in the 1-3 range so i would of thought it should be zero?

Comment: I think you're right. I just misread the number or something. Have updated the code. I also have a inefficient solution, could this help you help me? :)

Comment: did any of the below meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

If d is the input data frame create a function f(x, v) which returns a 1 for each element of x in vector v and 0 for the other elements.  Then cbind d[1] to the indicated expression.  No packages are used.

```
f <- function(x, v) +apply(x, 2, `%in%`, v)
cbind(d[1], c(f(d[1], 1:3)) * f(d[-1], 4:5) - c(f(d[1], 4:5)) * f(d[-1], 1:3))
```

giving

```
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
1    1    0    1    0    1
2    2    0    0    1    1
3    3    0    0    1    0
4    4    0   -1   -1   -1
5    5   -1    0   -1   -1
```

Here is a variation of that that assumes that only 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 occur (which is the case in the question's example).  First create a logical matrix m which is TRUE for each element that is 1, 2 or 3 and FALSE otherwise. Now we can use an expression similar to the one above

```
m <- d <= 3
cbind(d[1], (m[, 1] > m[, -1]) - (m[, -1] > m[, 1]))
```

or shorter

```
m <- d <= 3
cbind(d[1], m[, 1] - m[, -1])
```

Comment: ohh -- thoughtful approach with pmax!

Comment: Have simplified pmax to just a comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I think think the tidyverse solution can be simplified as such:

```r
library(tidyverse)

test |>
  mutate(across(-var1, 
                ~case_when(var1 %in% 1:3 & . %in% 4:5 ~ 1,
                           var1 %in% 3:5 & . %in% 1:2 ~ -1,
                           TRUE~ 0)))
#>   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
#> 1    1    0    1    0    1
#> 2    2    0    0    1    1
#> 3    3   -1    0    1    0
#> 4    4    0   -1   -1   -1
#> 5    5    0    0    0   -1
```

or another base r option:

```r
encode <- function(df){
  
  x <- matrix(rep(df[,1], ncol(df)-1), ncol = ncol(df)-1)
  y <- as.matrix(df[,2:ncol(df)])
  
  z <- matrix((x %in% 1:3 & y %in% 4:5) - (x %in% 3:5 & y %in% 1:2), 
              ncol = ncol(df)-1)
  
  cbind.data.frame(df[,1], z) |>
    `colnames<-`(colnames(df))
}

encode(test)
#>   var1 var2 var3 var4 var5
#> 1    1    0    1    0    1
#> 2    2    0    0    1    1
#> 3    3   -1    0    1    0
#> 4    4    0   -1   -1   -1
#> 5    5    0    0    0   -1
```

Comment: is there a way to use across() without column names (just numbers or positions?)

Comment: Yes, column numbers should work just fine. try `-c(1)` or `2:ncol(.)` or `2:ncol(_)` depending on what pipe you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a few ways to do this but this is my understanding of the logic and how to accomplish it.

```
library(tidyverse)

## get old names     
names_col <- colnames(df)

## bucket values by the max of the 1-3 range and min of 4-5 range
df_trans <- df %>% 
  mutate(
  across(everything(),~if_else(.x>3,4,3))
)

## apply difference between first column and other columns
df_temp <- purrr::list_cbind(
 map2(1,2:5,~df_trans[.y]-df_trans[.x])
)
## bring original first column and changed columns
df_temp_all <- bind_cols(df[[1]],df_temp) 

## get wrong names
wrong_names <- names(df_temp_all)

## create look up of names
names(wrong_names) <- names_col

## give correct names
df_temp_all %>% 
  rename(all_of(wrong_names))
```

Comment: there's a package called dplyover that is from @timteafan github which I think also would solve this easier but I'm still learning it.